# Future value prediction for unsampled data

Tags: algorithms, prediction

I am trying to study various factors that result in a single outcome. For example, if we look around factors that results in the stimuli reaction of a person, let's say the heart beat, the blood pressure, temp, and other factors that result in the stimuli reaction of a person, and what if there is any aletration in the data? How would the stimuli reaction be?

The example I give may not relate much, but I am looking for the existing algorithms that can help me to predict the next value for any kind of unsampled data.

I have Googled, but I would be grateful if anyone could help me around it and help me with the queries I have.

Thanks.

Comment: You will want to look into "statistics". You will need to fit a model, validate it, and based on that, you can do prediction. Here's a small example of calculating confidence intervals (http://rpubs.com/RomanL/7024), but I'd like to point out the last picture, lower to panels. This is sort of what you're after. I also made a small example of linear regression, see if you can find anything useful (http://rpubs.com/RomanL/7177).

Comment: Nick Thank you so much, i aapreciate it I will have a look can I have your email address to let you know about my exact query may you can help me with a direction

Comment: Perhaps you can expand your answer and give more details about your setup. Plenty of people reading this Q&A site who are more than able to give advice.